# How to prevent duplicated records?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I have no knowledge in CodeIgniter and would like some help. Here in the company where I work, there is a kind of booking system for dresses rental, so, the brides need to schedule a datetime through the online system before going to a store. That script was written with Codeigniter and what is the error: some records are being duplicated in database, I mean, the id keeps different, however in admin the same customer is being shown scheduled to the same datetime 4, 5 times, whatever. This is the code to create/insert a schedule in database:

```
$agendamento = Agendamento::create(array(
    'loja_id'           => $this->input->post('loja_id'),
    'usuario_id'        => $this->input->post('usuario_id'),
    'datahora'          => $this->input->post('datahora'),
    'loja'              => $loja->nome,
    'ultima_alteracao'  => date('Y-m-d h:j:s'),
    'status'            => 'D-2'
));
```

The above data comes through an ajax request, here:

```
$('#confirma_agendamento').on('click touchstart', function() {
    $.ajax({
        "dataType" : "text",
        "type" : "POST",
        "data" : {
            "loja_id" : loja_selecionada,
            "lista_espera" : lista_espera,
            "usuario_id" : usuario_id,
            "datahora" : data_selecionada + " " + hora_selecionada + ":00:00",
            //"vestidos" : $("#vestidos").val()
        },
        "url" : base_url + 'ajax/lojas/agendar',
        "success" : function (retorno) {
            if (retorno == '1') {
                window.location = SITE_URL + 'meus_agendamentos';
            }
            else {
                showModal('<h1>Erro</h1><p>Houve algum problema com o seu agendamento. Por favor tente novamente em alguns instantes.</p>');
            }
        },
        "error" : function() {
            showModal('<h1>Erro</h1><p>Houve algum problema com o seu agendamento. Por favor tente novamente em alguns instantes.</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

So, my question is: how to prevent duplicated records by datetime, I mean, avoid 2 records for the same datetime in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

in your ajax request url "url" : base_url + 'ajax/lojas/agendar', menas in ajx controller lojas method stay , you first need check the data which is already stay in or not in database . if data is found then not insert and if the data is not stay in database then write insert query